# Is there a substitution for multiple IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, class

So I tried using the same Id on multiple elements, and... It didn't work. I looked it up and it said that it wouldn't work. So it said that classes would be better. It didn't help though. This is my script:

```
<a class="links" style="position:absolute;top:30">Link 1</a>
<a class="links" style="position:absolute;top:10">Link 2</a>

<script>
links.href = "https://google.com";
</script>
```

But it still didn't work. Am I just doing it wrong? Do I do it another way?
Thanks for the help!

EDIT: For those of you who don't know, I'm trying to give the two links the same href. I'm not actually going to do that, but it's just an example of my problem.

Comment: The very idea of an id is to uniquely identify an element... whether it be in HTML or JavaScript or in any programming language under the sky. So no, you cannot have the same id for 2 different things in the same scope. Ever.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you trying to give all of your links the same href?

Comment: nnnnnn answered your question, but you also should using document.getElementByID or document.querySelector to get a reference to your DOM elements instead of just using href on the #id, (I know you're trying to use a class in this case but I get what you were doing before with ids.) This is just because your code will be difficult to debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to give all of your anchors with class `"links"` the same `href`, then you need to use one of the DOM methods that finds elements by class and returns a list of them, and then you need to *loop* over the items in the list.

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("links");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].href = "https://google.com";
}
```

Here I've used the [`.getElementsByClassName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), but you could also use the [`document.querySelectorAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) with a selector of `".links"`.